# Express is generating a new session on every API call

Tags: express, axios, cors, fetch

I have the following very basic setup for express

```
app.use(cors({ credentials: true, origin: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(sessions({
    secret: "thisismysecrctekeyfhrgfgrfrty84fwir767",
    saveUninitialized:false,
    resave: false,
    proxy: false,
    cookie: {
        path: '/',
        maxAge: null,
        httpOnly: false,
        secure: false, 
        sameSite: 'lax', // also tried 'none' or not setup at all
        name: 'app.sess.id',
      },
}));

// Tried it with and without this block
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", req.headers.origin);
    res.header(
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
      "Authorization, X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Allow-Request-Method"
    );
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
    res.header("Allow", "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
    next();
    });



app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    if (!req.session.views) {
        req.session.views = 0;
    }
    req.session.views++;
    console.log('---',req.session.id, req.session.views)

    res.send(JSON.stringify({ id: req.session.id, views: req.session.views }));
});



app.listen(port, () => console.log(`listening on port ${port || 3010}`))
```

Calling the app from the browser works as expected, the session remains the same as the browser is setting the session cookie.

However, when calling it from fetch/axios/xhr, the cookie is not set and the sessionId changes on every call.
A sample call

```
    fetch('http://localhost:3010', {
      credentials: 'include'
    })
```

Also tried the same with Axios

```
    axios.get('http://localhost:3010/', {
      withCredentials: true,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json', // Set the appropriate content type
      },
    })
```

I tried `same-origin` on the credentials but no luck. Any ideas what the configuration problem might be?

Comment: Whatever you do, never ever use `cors({ credentials: true, origin: true })`. Very insecure!

Comment: Also, don't set CORS headers in addition to using a CORS middleware.

Comment: @jub0bs it is but while trying to fix this you have to try everything before moving on. None of the configuration on the docs worked for me

Comment: Stop manually including CORS headers in your request. They're probably doing more harm than good. Then try again.

Comment: that's how i started, made no difference. It's right there on the comment above the headers

Comment: Sure, but you're better off not barking up the wrong tree. Now you can focus on configuring Express's CORS middleware properly.